# Plot same plot twice with matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, axes, subplot

I would like to plot the same mpl.pyplot.plot with different axes. My code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(211)
plot1 = plt.plot(data)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
:
much more stuff
:

plt.subplot(212)
command_to_plot(last_plot)
ax.set_xlim(a, b)
```

But unfortunately `command_to_plot` does not exist. So how can I do this?

Comment: Anything preventing you from defining `command_to_plot` yourself and putting all the plotting commands in this function?

Comment: The wish to avoid additional complexity and the passing of many arguments as well as the feeling that my computer should do the work of creating this plot only once.